# how to create more elements for the entered value in a textboxes in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I use for loop to create 3 textboxes with it's ids in javascript.. if I enter numbers on each text box I want to display same number of paragraphs element under each text box..

I have a problem: each textbox affected when i enter value in the other text boxes..

There is my codes:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {            
            var tx = document.createElement('input');
            tx.setAttribute('id', i);
            tx.onblur = function () {
                for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    var no = document.getElementById(i).value;
                    num = Number(no);
                    var d = document.getElementById('di' + i);
                for (x = 0; x < num; x++) {                    
                        var tx1 = document.createElement('p');
                        tx1.innerHTML = " p" + x;
                        d.appendChild(tx1);
                    }
                }
            };
            var div1 = document.createElement('div');
            div1.setAttribute('id', "di" + i);

            var div = document.getElementById('div1');
            div.appendChild(tx);
            div.appendChild(div1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are issues in code.
1) 

 `var div = document.getElementById('div1');
            div.appendChild(tx);`

The code is asking for div with ID div1 which is never appended to DOM hence it returns `null`
thus null.appendChild(tx) fails.

Thanks 
Added JSFiddle. If this is what you are trying to make..
http://jsfiddle.net/khm63wte/

Comment: Yes it is.. but if you can see the number entered in the second text affece the the first one.

Comment: Aaah ok.. then this is what you should be doing
http://jsfiddle.net/khm63wte/1/

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khm63wte/1/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just change your code, create a div on your document `<div id="t"></div>`, in your javascript create `div` first, then your `input` and append them to the document here is a working code

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {            
        var div1 = document.createElement('div');
        div1.setAttribute('id', "di" + i);
        document.getElementById('t').appendChild(div1)

        var tx = document.createElement('input');
        tx.setAttribute('id', i);
        document.getElementById("di"+i).appendChild(tx);
        tx.onblur = function () {
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                var no = document.getElementById(i).value;
                num = Number(no);
                var d = document.getElementById('di' + i);
            for (x = 0; x < num; x++) {                    
                    var tx1 = document.createElement('p');
                    tx1.innerHTML = " p" + x;
                    d.appendChild(tx1);
                }
            }
        };

 }
```